# Update quarkus CLI version on windows

Tags: quarkus

I have an installation of [Quarkus CLI](https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling#using-the-cli) on Windows and I just want to update to the latest version.

And searching for information, all I find are references to update the quarkus version in the pom xml or build gradle.

I just want to update the version of quarkus CLI on my Windows computer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see CLI version you can use

```
quarkus --version
```

for updating to latest with **jbang**

```
jbang app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio
```

for **sdkman**

```
sdk upgrade quarkus
```

for **homebrew**

```
brew update 
brew upgrade quarkus
```

for **chocolately**  <- for windows

```
choco upgrade quarkus
```

for **scoop** <- for windows

```
scoop update quarkus-cli
```

Usage example in linux with sdkman

[image: installing quarkus cli from sdkman]
Reference:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling

Comment: I'm confused. 

My original version is '3.6.9' 
Checked with 'quarkus -version' 

The latest published Quarkus version is '3.7.1' 

I have executed the instruction with jbang:
**jbang app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio** 

With the response: 
**[jbang] Command installed: quarkus** 

But if I check the version again: 
3.6.9 (It is not 3.7.1)

Comment: I do not know about jbang but just checked with **sdkman** and installed in my local, I put the screen shot to the answer. And I have 3.7.2. For windows I use choco and I checked their version https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/quarkus looks like they have the latest. please try with choco.

Comment: Surprise !!!
I haven't touched anything since last time, but I rechecked the quarkus version on my computer and it now shows 3.7.2
The only difference I suppose is that I have restarted the computer in between.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Anyway, I take note of the chocolately. Maybe I'll try it sometime.